# Random geometric series sums

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expected-value

Consider the classical geometric series $1,q,q^2,...$. The formula for the sum of the first n entries is well known. I would like to generalise this formula in the following way. Let X be a discrete random variable taking values $q_1, q_2,...,q_m$ with equal probability. Let $X_i\sim X$ be a sequence of iid random variables. I construct a stochastic process of the form
$Y_n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{i=1}^k X_i.$

Is there a formula for the expectation for the first hitting time $Y_n \geq Z$, where Z is a fixed value? This formula clearly has applications in financial planning, but I was not able to find any reference. I would be interested in any special case. Thank you!

Comment: I think to be dubbed geometric, even by analogy, the $q_i$ must somehow be powers or related multiplicatively to each other. Your expression in general has little resemblance to geometric progressions

Comment: @FShrike I think it does resemble. The difference is that instead of multiplying each term by a fixed constant, I multiply each precedent term by a random variable with a fixed distribution. If X takes a single value then this is exactly the geometric series and Y_n are the partial sums. But of course, the probabilistic case is much more difficult and I have no idea on how to analyse this process

Comment: I would guess that the probability of hitting $Z$ exactly at any time is $0$.  Suppose $X~U(0,1)$ and $Z=\frac32$.  Isn't $\Pr(\prod_{k=1}^nX_k=\frac12)=0$?

Comment: @saulspatz, My bad. It should be, of course, $Y_n \geq Z$, like for a discrete random walk